# Mirroring Phabricator repository to GCP Cloud Source Respository

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Phabricator to host my source code repository, and I would like to utilize GCP Cloud build for continuous build. One approach I find visible is to

1. Setup Phabricator repo mirror to GCP Cloud Source Repository (Need SSH key)
2. Once enters the GCP world, I can use Cloud Build connecting to Source Repository for continuous integration, etc.

In step 1, I want to use a service account so the Phabricator server can mirror the code without bounding to a specific engineer.

The problem is it requires a SSH key for git push, but I don't seem to find a way to create ssh key for the GCP service account.

Does anyone have a suggestion on any way to mirror Phabricator repository to GCP Cloud Source Respository

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-repositories), Mirroring Repositories in Cloud Source Repositories is available for **GitHub** and **Bitbucket** at the moment.

However, as a workaround you may consider [pushing to Cloud Source Repositories manually](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pushing-code-from-a-repository) or using an automation tool, like Jenkins, where the trigger would work similarly, without the mirroring part.